# Sending binary chunks to nodejs. Build file from binary

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hi ppl Im stuck with this. I want to be able to send file chunks through several `XMLHttpRequest` and, from nodejs, receive these parts and build the initial file from that binaries.

**The problem is that the result file isn't well formed. I guess because of encoding.**

on FE im using `file.slice` to split the file into several parts, this looks pretty fair as browser is setting `Content-Length` well..

on Backend Im using `fs.createWriteStream` to write binary data but likely encoding isn't correct somehow..

repo with instructions to reproduce the issue -> https://github.com/k1r0s/node-xhr-chunked-upload

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error was because I was converting a buffer into a string

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

I realized that and I just concatenate all buffers into a single one.

https://github.com/k1r0s/node-xhr-chunked-upload/commit/a724895293bca85c254cfdfec82c3226df5e2945